# Is there a way to store a file along with data(text, etc) in a database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, gridfs

I have failed in storing text and an image in a single database and I would appreciate some assistance

Comment: do you mean storing text and images separately or together?

Comment: storing images and text together

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use get and post to read and write to a txt file, you can do this with jquery and node's framework express. In Node create a file for the server side:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express()

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening...'))

app.use(express.static('public')) // public folder with client side js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/get', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('test.txt', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.json(JSON.parse(data));
    })
})


app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    var text1 = req.body.text
    console.log(text1)
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', text1, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
    })
})
```

In jquery to store the content of the file in variable and do something with it:

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost:3000/get", function( data ) {
geojsondata1 = JSON.stringify(data)
alert( "Received data from server!" + geojsondata1 );
}
```

In jquery to change the file do a post:

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000/post', {text: texttopost}) // texttopost is what you want to write in the txt file
```